# Applescript - How to get text range of a word in Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word, applescript

E.g.

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    tell active document
        set theRange to text range of word 5 of content of text object
        ...
     end tell
end tell
```

I am trying to get the text range to convert the word to a link via 'make new hyperlink'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me using the latest version of Mac OS Sierra

Try this version for using the word number

```
chosenWord(5)

on chosenWord(wordNumber)
    tell application "Microsoft Word"
        tell its document 1
            set theWord to content of word wordNumber
            tell its word wordNumber
                set {theStartOfRange, theEndOfRange} to {start of content, end of content}
                set theRange to ("The Character Range Is " & (theStartOfRange as text) & " thru " & (theEndOfRange as text))
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end chosenWord
```

**OR**

Try this version for using the current selection in the document

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    set theSelection to content of words of selection
    set {selectionStart, selectionEnd} to ¬
        {selection start of selection, selection end of selection}
    set theRange to selectionStart & selectionEnd
end tell
return theRange
```

Comment: is there any way we can get the range of selected text from Safari and Mail using appleScript?